# Blazor Date picker type week doesn't work on iOS

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor

I have blazor server applciation and I have a sample input text type **week**, it works fine in all browsers except in apple devices, it see the input as type text!. 
This my code :

```
Dictionary<string, object> typeInput= new Dictionary<string, object> { { "type", "week" } };
private string WeekVal { get; set; }// in the initialize the value it will be come like `WeekVal = $"{Year}-W{Week}";`
<InputText @attributes="typeInput" 
           min="@($"{DateTime.Now.Year}-W{(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear / 7)}")"
           Value="@WeekVal" 
           ValueChanged="@((e) => OnWeekChange(e))"
           ValueExpression="@(() => WeekVal)"
           class="form-control" required />
```

My question, Could you please give me some work around this error?

Comment: Can you post the HTML rendering? What is WeekVal for examplw and the `min` might be a not understandable format

Comment: Sorry, I can't copy the html from phone to here :( , I use phone as simulator. Why do you think that `min` is not understandable!

Comment: The MDN page on [input type="week"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week) shows that Firefox and Safari don't support this type. You should try to find a date picker component

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think you are right, I would you like to create my custom component. Do you have some advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input type `week` is not supported by Safari on iOS.
https://caniuse.com/input-datetime

> Partial support in iOS Safari refers to not supporting the week input type, nor the min, max or step attributes.

Depending on your target audience, it also will not work in the following browsers: Firefox, Desktop Safari.

If you want to have a week selector that also works in iOS and these other browsers you'll have to resort to a web-based date picker, instead of a browser native one.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I don't speak about Safari, even Microsoft Edge doesn't work on apple and I need week :(